# Visual studio reads external keypad directly, not via lua script mapper

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, lua

I have an external numeric keypad which I use for macros, etc.
This is mapped via a lua script which runs at startup and simply maps the keys on the keypad to simple key combinations (ctrl+C, shft+alt+l, etc)

This is working fine across my desktop, I have tested it using notepad, outlook, slack, etc.
When I try this in visual studio 2015 professional (text editor) I get the original keys from the keypad, not my mappings.

Does anyone know if VS reads this device differently and if so, can I bypass this.
I'm pretty sure this was working fine on my desktop but seems broken on my laptop.

Visual studio pro 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Resharper ultimate 2017.1.3
very few extensions other than defaults

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out
The script runner only works under a single user (ie the one that started it)
I was running VS as admin and the keypad was not mapped for this.
Running the script as admin solves this problem but prevents all other apps from getting the keys mapped